# Are there exercises similar to the 'Buddha rope' for endurance on bass guitar?

Tags: technique, practice, exercises, electric-bass-guitar

The "Buddha rope" technique described by Bill 'The Buddha' Dickens in his training DVD basically entails putting a rope between strings and then using the increased tension for building muscles in your hands consistently. I've tried looking for a video to explain the technique, but Youtube seems to have removed most copies.

[image]

This technique done consistently (daily) works great for fingerstyle (speed and endurance).

Are there similar exercises (or consistency hacks) for getting your thumb technique, slapping and popping or even tapping techniques very consistent?

Comment: I did some looking, and it seems the technique is to put the rope under the strings to raise the action, which makes that fretting harder. But that's a fretting-hand technique. I have no advice for getting your picking hand in shape, which is why I commented and didn't answer.

Comment: Gary Willis has some videos out there that are kinda old, but he goes over a lot of detail hoe to work on the right hand for bass. [Gary Willis - Progressive Bassics Pt. 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u82A7ILPKHE)

Answer (score 2):

Not really a technique but try interlacing an elastic band (kind of loosely) around your strings near the bridge to try and kill some of the initial transient and deaden the strings a bit. To get a good slapping, popping or tapping tone with the stings deadened like this will require great "right" hand technique but your "Left" hand will have to be very precise as well.

Comment: if we can get some links and punch up this answer a bit I'll give it the bounty.